# load associated objects in a to_json :method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am rendering out some json like this:

```
render :json => r.to_json(:methods => ['food_item','drink_item'])
```

Both food_item and drink_item have a `has_one` associated price. How could I load this to be rendered in the json?

thx

**edit #1**
Here's some more code - wrote late last night:

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  #price
  has_one :price, :as => :pricable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :price
end

class ObjectConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def food_item
    MenuItem.find(food_id)
  end

  def drink_item
    MenuItem.find(drink_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please post your model code?

Answer (score 2):

In this you need use the `:include` args in your method `food_item` and `drink_item`

```
def food_item
  food_item.to_json(:include => :my_has_one)
end

def drink_item
  drink_item.to_json(:include => :my_has_one)
end
```

Comment: there's no way I can just specify at the rendering of the json rather than at model layer?